# Comparing two arrays and merging without duplicates

Tags: javascript, angular

```
var a = [{id: 14679333, name: "Churchill Downs", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Gulfstream", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, 
         {id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}]


var b = [{id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Charles Town", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
         {id: 14679333, name: "Los Alamitos", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}]
```

Code:

```
 for(var i=0; i< b.length;i++){
   if((b[i].typeName || b[i].name) != (a[i].typeName || a[i].name)){
    var c= a.concat(b)
     console.log("after concat",c)
   }
 }
```

I am trying to compare both arrays and merge into single array without duplicates but I am getting this output:

```
c= [{id: 14679333, name: "Churchill Downs", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Gulfstream", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Charles Town", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
{id: 14679333, name: "Los Alamitos", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}]
```

Expected output:

```
c = [{id: 14679333, name: "Churchill Downs", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
     {id: 14679333, name: "Gulfstream", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
     {id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
     {id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
     {id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
     {id: 14679333, name: "Charles Town", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"},
     {id: 14679333, name: "Los Alamitos", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's too much code and any explanation here. Try also to adjust your formatting please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and look for same name and filter the array of all items.

```js
var a = [{ id: 14679333, name: "Churchill Downs", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Gulfstream", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }],
    b = [{ id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Charles Town", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }, { id: 14679333, name: "Los Alamitos", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true" }],
    result = [...a, ...b]
        .filter(
            (s => ({ name }) => !s.has(name) && s.add(name))
            (new Set)
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement `(b[i].typeName || b[i].name) != (a[i].typeName || a[i].name)` is incorrect, even if I know what you mean in spoken english.

It should be `(b[i].typeName == a[i].typeName) || (b[i].typeName == a[i].name) || (b[i].name == a[i].typeName) || (b[i].name == a[i].name)`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if ((b[i].typeName == a[i].typeName) || (b[i].typeName == a[i].name) || (b[i].name == a[i].typeName) || (b[i].name == a[i].name)) {
    var c = a.concat(b)
    console.log("after concat", c)
  }
}
```

At the moment, `(b[i].typeName || b[i].name)` by itself will return `false`, as will, `(a[i].typeName || a[i].name)`. The full statement therefore always returns `false`.

What I presume you want to do is ask "is [either this one or this one] equal to [either this one or this one]". To achieve this, you'll have to go through all four combinations one at a time, which is what my code does.

Answer (score 0):

Merge your arrays to a new one, then kill the duplicates:

merge:

```
let newArr = [...a, ...b];
```

The following filter code will NOT work, if the reference of the inner objects are not the same:

```
newArr = newArr.filter((item, pos) => {
    return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
```

Solution:

In your case do the filtering with this code, if you want to have the name property unique:

```
let newArr = [...a, ...b];
const temp = {};
for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
  temp[newArr[i].name]= newArr[i];
}
newArr = [];
for (let key in temp) {
  newArr.push(temp[key]);
}
console.info(newArr);
console.info(newArr.map( o => o.name).sort());
```

--> 7 items

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are great. You can achive this with single line, give this code a try:

```js
var a = [{id: 14679333, name: "Churchill Downs", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Gulfstream", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}]
var b = [{id: 14679333, name: "Santa Anita", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Charles Town", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Golden Gate Fields", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Remington Park", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}, {id: 14679333, name: "Los Alamitos", eventStatusCode: "A", isActive: "true"}];

var combined = [...a, ...b];
var filtered = [...new Map(combined.map(val=>[val.name, val])).values()];
console.log(filtered);
```